# Not Able to setup python | SSL Error

Tags: server, python, openssl

Facing issues to setup the environment in Ubuntu 22.04 tried all the possible solutions like getting development libraries and installing openssl in the home directory but no luck.

[image: Error]

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry (total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError (SSLEOFError (8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl 129) '))': /simple/pandas/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ss1 certificate: HITPSConnectionPool (host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with uri: ple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError (SSLEOFError (8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129) '))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Please assist me in getting it resolved.

Comment: Have you tried to access that URL with a web browser or ping it?